# How to find duplicate character in string without using in built methods of String Class in java methods like length(),toCharArray(),charAt()?

Tags: java, string, duplicates, character

How to find the duplicate character in the string without using inbuilt methods of String Class in java methods like `length()`, `toCharArray()`, `charAt()`?

Ask in an interview please give me solutions on this

```
input : abcdeddrb
output: db
```

Comment: What's your attempt?

Comment: If you can't use _any_ built-in methods, you have no way of checking the contents of the string.

Comment: If someone asks you "How would you detect duplicate characters in a String without using any existing methods of the String class" the only correct answer is "I wouldn't, because that's stupid and pointless." Seriously some of those "smart and innovative" interview questions just makes you question the sanity of the interviewer and company asking them.

Comment: The output doesn't seem correct. Why is there `c`, `e` and `r`? I don't see those duplicated in the input.

Comment: The letter `a` is not a duplicate character in your input string `abcdeddrb`, and neither is `c` or `e`.  Only `b` and `d` occur more than once.

Comment: After getting some feedback, I agree with @OHGODSPIDERS and if you can't access and `String` methods, then the interview question seems pointless to me.

Comment: sorry for wrong output by mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change `String` to [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and use its methods as `charAt`

```
  CharSequence cs = s;
```

Comment: This can't possibly be the point of the interview question.  This is like saying serve me a beer, but don't use a glass.  So you give it to me in a dirty boot instead.  It's still beer though.

Comment: please give me the complete solution

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with reflection:

```java
public String findDuplicateChars(String input)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field valueField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    valueField.setAccessible(true);
    char[] chars = (char[]) valueField.get(input);

    List<Character> duplicatedChars = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char aChar = chars[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < chars.length; j++) {
            char anotherChar = chars[j];
            if (aChar == anotherChar) {
                if (!duplicatedChars.contains(aChar)) {
                    duplicatedChars.add(aChar);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    char[] charArray = new char[duplicatedChars.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < duplicatedChars.size(); i++) {
        charArray[i] = duplicatedChars.get(i);
    }

    return new String(charArray);
}
```

Since `b` is the first duplicated `char` the output will be `bd` though, not `db`.

Maybe the point of the interview's question was to check if you know reflection or to check if you would try to quit the interview with an answer like "Why should anyone do that?".

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that your interviewer wanted you to use a map to keep track of which characters have been seen and which have not.

```
String input = "abcdeddrb";
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int i=0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
    Integer count = map.get(input.charAt(i));
    map.put(input.charAt(i), count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
}

map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);

b=2
d=3
```

Comment: You use still use `String.length()`

Comment: @user7294900 I agree with your comment.  I will leave this up just in case this is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Strictly no use inbuilt function

Comment: Honestly I think this is a trick question.  If that company really values questions like this, then you might want to not take that offer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testStr = "abcdeddrb";

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Character, Integer> duplicateStrMap = null;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    CharacterIterator it = new StringCharacterIterator(testStr);

    // Loop Characters in a String.
    for (char c = it.first(); c != CharacterIterator.DONE; c = it.next()) {

        if(map.containsKey(c)){
            if(duplicateStrMap == null){
                duplicateStrMap = new HashMap<>();
            }
            duplicateStrMap.put(c, count);
            count++;
        }
        else{
            map.put(c, ++i);
        }
    }

    // Print Results
    if(duplicateStrMap != null){

        System.out.println("Total Duplcates Found :"+duplicateStrMap.size());            
        Iterator<Character> itr = duplicateStrMap.keySet().iterator();

        System.out.println("Duplicate Characters :");

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Total Duplcates Found :2
>  Duplicate Characters :
>  b
>  d

Comment: Try using CharacterIterator. Hope this is useful.

Comment: Well, StringCharacterIterator still use String.charAt() when it calls it.first() or it.next()

Comment: No inbuilt function bro -- Nag Ram

Comment: no other inbuilt method please give the correct answer

Comment: No inbuilt functions of string class is used. CharacterIterator is part of java.text package.